# Smoothness of Schubert Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, invariant-theory, schubert-calculus

Consider the Schubert variety $X(s_3s_2s_1s_4s_3s_2)$ in $SL_5/P_2$, where $P_2$ is the maximal parabolic corresponding to the simple root $\alpha_2$. In one line notation this permutation can be written as $(45123)$. Since $(4512) > (3412)$ this Schubert variety is Singular by the pattern avoidance criterion. But this Schubert variety is the full Grassmannian $SL_5/P_2$ and hence smooth. Am I missing something  ? On the other hand the Schubert variety $X(s_2s_1s_4s_3s_2)$ is singular. What are the irreducible components of the singular locus ?

Comment: Could you give a reference for the pattern avoidance criterion?

Comment: Smooth Schubert Varieties In Partial Flag Manifolds by Gasharov and Reiner and the link is http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.6429

Comment: I don't have time to check the calculations right now, but you are sure that the given element is of maximal length?

Comment: The calculation goes like this: Call this permutation $w$, we have $(w(1), w(2))=(4,5)$. So the element in $S_5$ is $(45123)$ (In one line notation). I don't know how to get an element of maximal length from here.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a good method to find a coset representative os maximal length, but you need to check that your elements is one, or the cited result does not apply.

Comment: Just to be clear: When you say maximal parabolic corresponding to a simple root, you mean the subgroup generated by all the other simple roots?

Comment: yes, it ii generated by Borel and all the $U_{-\alpha_i}, i \neq 2$.

Comment: In that case, the element is not maximal in its coset. You can for example multiply by either $s_1$ or $s_3$ from the right and get something longer.

Comment: Yes, I found out that it is the minimal coset representative not the maximal. Yes we can multiply $s_1$ or $s_3$ to get a longer one but how far can we go ?

Comment: Well, keep multiplying with things from the parabolic subgroup until you get an element such that any of the generators of the parabolic can appear on the right in a reduced expression of the element.

Comment: There should be a better way to do this. In Macaulay-2 there is a command to get the minimal representative of an element but not the maximal one.

Comment: I agree that there ought to be a good way to do it (at least a computer should be able to). The lack of a command for it is probably because minimal length representatives seem to show up more often (especially in relation to Hecke algebras)

Comment: The maximal representative is $(54321)$ which still does not avoid the pattern $(3412)$. So I am missing something here.

Comment: That certainly does avoid the pattern (the pattern is up-down-up or down-up-down)

Comment: What is the relative order ? Here I believe that $(5432) > (3412)$.

Comment: The relative order is that of the elements when written in one-line notation. It is not an ordering on the permutations.

Comment: Still not clear. Everything written so far are in one line notation.

Comment: Right, the pattern to avoid in the one-line notation is $x,y,z,w$ with $x > y$, $y < z$ and $z > w$ (or all those inequalities reversed).

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear to me. However $(53421)$ doesn't avoid the pattern because it contains the subsequence $(5342)$. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, precisely.